# What is the difference between ADAL.js and MSAL.js?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to handle authentication for my app which uses Microsoft Graph.

What is the difference between these two libraries?

- [Active Directory Authentication Library for JavaScript (ADAL.js)](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)
- [Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript (MSAL.js)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)

Is ADAL.js just an Angular 1 library of MSAL.js?

Comment: There is also a documentation from Microsoft explaining more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-compare-msal-js-and-adal-js

Answer (score 25, accepted):

MSAL.js works with the AzureAD V2 endpoint, whereas ADAL.js works with the AzureAD V1 endpoint. The V1 endpoint supports work accounts, but not personal accounts. The V2.0 endpoint is the unification of Microsoft personal accounts and work accounts into a single authentication system. Finally, with msal.js you can also get authentications for Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Nice explanation, [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) a nice doc that compares the two endpoints as well.

Comment: In the future, please provide a source and quote the text that you did not write yourself. I've edited your answer accordingly.