# adal.js or msal.js for ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, azure, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am reading through Azure Active Directory support for OAuth2 for SPA (my wish is to go for Reactjs). I have found 2 libraries for Javascrip: adal.js and msal.js. Since I am new to SPA I would need an advice from experts here. I have also read this: [What is the difference between ADAL.js and MSAL.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526652/what-is-the-difference-between-adal-js-and-msal-js)
Therefore my question is what should i use adal.js or msal.js if i need to implement a SPA with Microsoft IdP (v1 or v2) and using ReactJS?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ADAL.js and MSAL.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526652/what-is-the-difference-between-adal-js-and-msal-js)

Comment: i have mentioned that page indeed. But my question is specifically for ReactJS. tks

Answer (score 0):

The selection from these two libraries is up to you. Both can be used to work with Azure Active Directory. Because MSAL.js is still under development. That is why I prefer ADAL.js That means you have to use adal-angular. You might find out good a documentation and many examples for that. The reason you have to use adal-angular is still there is no adal library for React.

Comment: many thanks. But then if i want to use ReactJS i should go for msal.js ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have also used adal.js with ReactJS. No need to go to msal.js. I am still saying if you need to go for masl.js. That is totally up to you.